# How do I override all error pages in Bottle?

Tags: python, bottle

Bottle lets me override the handler for specific errors with [`Bottle.error`](https://bottlepy.org/docs/0.12/api.html#bottle.Bottle.error), but I'm making a JSON API and I want to override **all** errors with a single handler so I can return JSON.

Something like this would be optimal if it worked:

```
@bottle.error()
def error_handler(error):
    # ...
```

Unfortunately, unless I specify a HTTP status code, the handler is ignored.

Can this be done?

---

**Edit**: Turns out the handler isn't actually ignored, it defaults to 500. That has no bearing on the question though.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through the source a bit, and I found the default error handler. There doesn't seem to be a way to override it without subclassing, so this is what I ended up with:

```
class JSONBottle(bottle.Bottle):
    def default_error_handler(self, error):
        return json.dumps({"error": "unexpected error"})

app = JSONBottle()

@app.error(404)
def error_404(error):
    return json.dumps({"error": "resource not found"})
```

This sets a sane default error message for a JSON API, and it lets me override it for specific errors later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the workaround I'm currently using. It's pretty ugly, but I haven't found a better way yet.

```
def error_handler(error):
    out = {"message": error.body}

    if 400 <= error.status_code < 500:
        out["code"] = "input_error"

    elif error.status_code >= 500:
        out["code"] = "server_error"

    else:
        out["code"] = "???"

    return json.dumps(out)

for code in [int(x) for x in bottle.HTTP_CODES.keys() if x >= 400]:
    bottle.error(code)(error_handler)
```